# What is the meaning of 'code' in Segmentation Fault

Tags: android, linux

I see these 2 segmentation faults in android. 
One said SEGV_MAPERR, the other said SEGV_ACCERR.

Can you please tell me what are the differences between these 2?

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 41963214

signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 4006e000
```

Thanks.

Comment: `SEGV_MAPERR` is a memory allocation error (dangling pointer, memory overflow etc), `SEGV_ACCERR` is a memory access error, usually permissions.  Or are you looking for something more?

Comment: Is it fair to say SEGV_ACCERR is caused by stack corruption?

Comment: Well, I guess it could be if you used a stack pointer to access memory you have no permissions to, but it seems unlikely.  What are you doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per [siginfo.h](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/merakidev/include/bits/siginfo.h):

SEGV_MAPERR means you tried to access an address that doesn't map to anything.

SEGV_ACCERR means you tried to access an address that you don't have permission to access.

So in both cases you accessed an address you shouldn't have, which is probably the only thing your actual code is guilty of. In the former case there's no memory in that address range anyway. In the latter case there is memory in that address range but you don't own it.

If you were to access a random address then which you get depends on how the OS happens to have your process set up at that moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you access a memory like `*((int*)0)=1`, you will get `SEGV_MAPERR`.

If you protected a memory with `mprotect(2)`, e.g., `mprotect(buffer, pagesize, PROT_READ)`, then you modified the memory like `*(buffer)=1`, you will get `SEGV_ACCERR`.

Please `man mprotect` for detail.